# LDAP on non-Server OSX

Tags: high-sierra, ldap

I have read where Apple plans to stop making OSX server.  What does this mean for LDAP services?  Is it possible to install LDAP on a regular mac running High Sierra? Could my own iMac be the LDAP server for my organization in other words?

Answer (score 4):

macOS Server is keeping LDAP with no published plans for it to be removed. See:

- [Prepare for changes to macOS Server - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208312)

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question(s)

> Is it possible to install LDAP on a regular mac running High Sierra?

and

> Could my own iMac be the LDAP server for my organization in other
>   words?

Yes on both counts, though I wouldn't put LDAP server on a production workstation (if you turn off your iMac, LDAP goes down for everyone)  You could put it on a Mac mini (two would be better) and let it run as server 24/7.

LDAP is just a service much like SSH, Apache, or DHCP.  You don't need a server version of an OS to run a server instance.

[OpenLDAP](http://formulae.brew.sh/repos/Homebrew/homebrew-core/formula/openldap) is available via Homebrew and you can run this on your plain macOS machine.

That said (non-Apple solution follows) I probably wouldn't run LDAP on a Mac - it's just too expensive (hardware wise).  I would get two cheap PCs, load up FreeBSD (what Mac is based on) and fire up OpenLDAP on each.

Comment: This is happy news.  My thought was to get two mac mini's (we have a few at hand already) and have them run High Sierra (not server) and have them run LDAP in kind of a load balanced or at least master/slave kind of way.  Can you recommend any articles on setting them up?

Comment: The best one I know of is from the [FreeBSD manual](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/ldap-auth/ldap.html)  It should follow the setup for Mac, but I personally haven't tested it.  At the very minimum, it's a good primer